# How to see the (XYZ) axis on a unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, code-injection, axis

I think the title said everything. I want to make an program that it will find the axis on the game that i inject on. My player axis. But i don't have a clue on how to do this. I am using C# language. Thanks !!

Comment: Do you have any attempts, or code for us to work with? We're not here to do your projects for you.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand true 
you have external axis detector like **wii remote** or a sender axis software

you should use [system.io class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspxxAOT864ym6WKAA) and streaming data

dont remember
in unity C# you should add system.io.stream.dll and in start of your script add 
using system.io;